# Can code contracts cross-cut concerns of code?

Tags: .net-4.0, code-contracts

Is there a way to specify code contract requirements that are cross-cutting, for example a contract at the class level to require an instance variable to be non-null whenever any instance method on that class is invoked, or else the call will fail?

I'm new to code contracts and have been skimming the [Feb 4, 2011 Code Contracts User Manual (PDF)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/2/7/C2715F76-F56C-4D37-9231-EF8076B7EC13/userdoc.pdf) and the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992) but nothing pops out at me about cross-cutting features.   Maybe I'm searching for a feature that code contracts do not have.

Comment: Thanks @darvids0n, for kicks I changed the word "aspects" to "concerns" in the title to make it even more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for are called "object invariants"

From the manual, § 2.3

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant () 
{
   Contract.Invariant ( this.y >= 0 );
   Contract.Invariant ( this.x > this.y );
}
```

They will be checked *after* each public method call.
For properly encapsulated values that should be the same as before each call.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll have to spend more time with it because the contract method seems to not be accessed when any of my public methods are called, tested by putting the line `throw new Exception("fyi - contract area");` inside the ObjectInvariant() method.

Comment: For posterity I found this additional tutorial and example on Code Project of using ContractInvariantMethod http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CodeContracts_Pt2.aspx?

Comment: @John: It is a matter of settings (you will need FULL) but this is no ordinary method and it is not treated/executed as one. Your `throw` test won't work, just try breaking one of the contracts.

Comment: Thanks Hank. In addition to what's in the .NET Fmk4 I had to install Code Contracts from DevLabs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx to get the counterpart 'Code Contracts' VS project tab, so I could enable runtime checking - that seemed to do the trick.  You're right about not using the Exception as a test. Now my code contract is failing as it should. The scenario in my question of implementing one instance field check across all method calls is sufficed.

Comment: The only thing that didn't fit well to what I actually want to do is the ObjectInvariant method is run at the **end** of the public method call, not at the beginning, as a post-condition check. That reasoning is described in Code Project as: *"the invariant is checked as a post condition so that you can have a public method in an instance call another public method in the instance without executing the post condition in the second public method."* http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CodeContracts_Pt2.aspx?